# Definition of universal bundle in category of smooth manifolds

Tags: principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $(P, M, G)$ a smooth principal bundle over smooth manifold $M$ with Lie group $G$. We denote by $k_{G}(M)$ the set of all classes of principal G-bundle isomorphisms. If i want to define universal bundles in the smooth object category do i have to take the definition that the pullback construction

$$[X, M] \rightarrow k_{G}(X),$$
for all smooth manifold $X$ is a bijection? Or do I have to consider more general X spaces?

Appreciate.

Comment: Universal bundles don't exist in the category of smooth manifolds. The classifying space is too large. You need to extend to Banach manifolds or whatever your taste is.

Comment: Thanks, Mike Miller.